# Create a stored procedure to select data from multiple tables SQL Server WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, stored-procedures

I'm trying to get some information from database and show it in a DataGrid but it is quite slow to get the information because I am getting data from multiple tables. I need to speed it up. Here is how my database tables are structured

```
TestPack (Id, test_pack_no, train_no, .....)
Sheet (id, **testPackId**, sheet_no, ....)
Spool (id, **sheetId**, spool_no, bore_size, ....)
FieldJoint(id, **spoolId**, thickness, size, ...)
```

Here is the code which creates a List of FieldJoints ( a custom class with required fields of Testpack, Sheet, Spool and FIeldJoint).

```
foreach (var tp in allTestPacks)
{
    foreach (var sheet in tp.Sheets)
    {
        foreach (var spool in sheet.Spools)
        {
            foreach (var joint in spool.FieldJoints)
            {
                var newJoint = new FieldJoint
                {
                    TestPackNo = tp.test_pack_no,
                    TrainNo = tp.train_no,
                    IsometricNo = spool.sheet_no,
                    SpoolNo = spool.spool_no,
                    BoreSize = spool.bore_size,
                    Thickness = joint.joint_thickness.Value,
                    JointSize = joint.joint_size.Value,
                };
                _fieldJointsInfo.Add(newJoint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe if I can create a stored procedure that runs directly on the server machine where database is hosted, it will speed up the performance. How can I convert the above code into a stored procedure that would take input a string "trainNo" and return all the above information based on that trainNo which is a column in TestPack table.

Comment: Create a procedure with parameters such as TestPackNo, TrainNo etc. 
In the procedure have an insert statement...

Comment: @Alex, I don't think that the OP wanted to insert or update... It's just - if I got this correctly - reading from database to fill a grid. This is much better be done with a function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to read related data. You do not show all your code, but reading data in nested for-loops sounds like a pain in the neck...

What about a function like this?

#### Attention: Make sure to have indexes on your key and foreign key columns...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetTestPackDetails
(
    @TrainNo VARCHAR(100)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
SELECT tp.Id AS TestPackId
      ,tp.test_pack_no
      ,tp.train_no
      ,sh.id AS SheetId
      ,sh.sheet_no
      ,sp.id As SpoolId
      ,sp.spool_no,sp.bore_size
      ,fj.id AS FieldJointId
      ,fj.thikness
      ,fj.size 
      --add more columns...
FROM TestPack AS tp
    INNER JOIN Sheet AS sh ON tp.Id=sh.testPackId
        INNER JOIN Spool AS sp ON sh.id=sp.sheetId
            INNER JOIN FieldJoint AS fj ON sp.id=fj.spoolId
WHERE tp.train_no=@TrainNo;
```

You can call this with

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetTestpackDetails('TheTrainNo');
```

In C# you might create a typed DataSet directly from this function.

Btw: I would **not** use a Stored Procedure just to **read** data. SPs are meant **to do** something...

Comment: @Shrugo thanks for this. a little more help. How would this be called from C# using Entity Framework approach?

Comment: @WasimQadir, Up to now I haven't done anything with EF. All projects I'm working on use kind of but different ORM.

Comment: @Shrugo thanks for the idea of a function. this has boosted up performance big time :)